# Convert TinyMce plugin (filemanager) for use in form

Tags: javascript, plugins, tinymce

I have recently found a filemanager plugin for my TinyMCE, but I want to use the same filemanager outside TinyMCE inside a form. (https://github.com/2b3ez/FileManager4TinyMCE - Filemanager4TinyMCE)

Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$('#select-button').click(function(){
        var win,data,dom=editor.dom,imgElm=editor.selection.getNode();
        var width,height,imageListCtrl;
        win=editor.windowManager.open({
            title:'File Manager',
            file:'js/tinymce/plugins/filemanager/dialog.php?editor=select-button&lang=undefined',filetype:'all',
            classes:'filemanager',width:900,height:600,inline:1
            })
            });</script>
<input type="file" id="select-button" />
```

There are some javascript files, but I am not familiar with it.
Here is the file, where I got the javascript above from:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add(
'filemanager',
function(editor){
    function openmanager(){
        var win,data,dom=editor.dom,imgElm=editor.selection.getNode();
        var width,height,imageListCtrl;
        win=editor.windowManager.open({
            title:'File Manager',
            file:'js/tinymce/plugins/filemanager/dialog.php?editor='+editor.id+'&lang='+tinymce.settings.language,filetype:'all',
            classes:'filemanager',width:900,height:600,inline:1
            })
            }
    editor.addButton('filemanager',{
        icon:'browse',
        tooltip:'Insert file',
        onclick:openmanager,
        stateSelector:'img:not([data-mce-object])'
    });
    editor.addMenuItem('filemanager',{
        icon:'browse',
        text:'Insert file',
        onclick:openmanager,
        context:'insert',
        prependToContext:true
    })
});
```

But I think some files of TinyMCE or its plugins need to be edited in some way, in order to make the plugin 'stand-alone'.